# How to pass unnest function as function input paramter in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
  select e.emp_id, e.empname, e.sal
  from unnest(array[1,2], array['A','B'],array[1000,5000]) as e(emp_id, mpname, sal);
$function$;
```

How we can pass the `emp_id`,`empname`, `sal` values through function parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to be able to specify which columns you want to select from the table, you will have to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Make sure to use the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functionhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMATml#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function like in

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT %I, %I FROM ...', p_col1, p_col2) INTO v_result;
```

That will keep you safe from SQL injection.

If what you want is to pass the values of `emp_id`, `mpname` and `sal` that you use in the `FROM` clause, you can use static SQL. Just replace `array[1,2]` with the name of a parameter that has type `integer[]`.